# Django left join query on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, django

I have defined three models that are as below

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(...)    

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(...)
    city = models.ManyToManyFields(City)

class MenuItemCount(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    menu_count = models.IntegerField()
```

One note is that all restaurants and cities might not exist in MenuCount. So a left join is needed.

I am trying to write the django query to retrieve a list of restaurant name, city name and menu counts. Example result would be

```
restaurant1, city1, 20
restaurant1, city2, None
restaurant2, city2, 30
restaurant3, city1, None
```

How can I write a query for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the data in 1 query, you can use `prefetch_related`. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Here is the example.

```
City.objects.prefetch_related('restaurant_set', 'menuitemcount_set').all()
```